# Greenhouse gases

Tags: thermal-radiation, climate-science

A post (below) on the Bishop Hill blog relating to climate change asserts that no warming effect can be attributed to $\mathrm{CO_2}$. I don't know whether the author is really a physicist but it sounds impressive ([Planck spectra and black-body radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_spectrum) etc). Can someone explain in layman's language whether the assertions are valid.

Quote from http://www.bishop-hill.net/blog/2012/4/5/greenhouse-reversal.html

```
There is no greenhouse, so it can't be reversed.

Many so-called skeptics are not really basing their arguments on the true
physics of the atmosphere. By failing to do so, they are demonstrating
that they also have fallen for the IPCC bluff that radiation from a cooler
atmosphere (including so-called backradiation, but also initial radiation)
can transfer thermal energy to a warmer surface.

This is not correct physics and the sooner this is made clear to the
public the better. True physics, backed up by basic phenomena such as the
fact that radiation in a microwave oven is not absorbed in the usual sense
of the word, shows why this is the case. No one has ever proved anything
to the contrary in any empirical experiment, and never will.

The only thing any such radiation from the atmosphere can do is slow down
that third or so of surface cooling which occurs by way of radiation that
does not escape to space via the atmospheric window. Radiation from the
atmosphere can have absolutely no effect on evaporative cooling, chemical
processes or sensible heat transfer. These non-radiative components plus
the radiation to space make up about 70% of all surface
cooling. Furthermore, the effect of carbon dioxide with its limited
frequencies is far less than a true blackbody, and less per molecule than
water vapor. No gas can radiate outside its Planck spectrum (i.e. more than
a true blackbody) and so there is no way that carbon dioxide (1 in 2,500
molecules) can contribute a very large amount of radiation anyway.

The other cooling processes merely accelerate and compensate for any
minuscule slowing of radiative cooling. Thus there is absolutely no
warming attributable to carbon dioxide. It is time for skeptics to get
their facts right and stop giving in to part of the hoax. Only truth will
prevail in the long run.
```

EDIT:
The author of the blog post was 'Doug Cotton', who has published a related paper at http://principia-scientific.org/publications/psi_radiated_energy.pdf and has a website at http://climate-change-theory.com/

Comment: If you want answers drawing from a credible source, we can have this migrated to Skeptics.SE..

Comment: I imagined that a forum inhabited by physicists was the most credible source :-)  The statements above seem so authoritative and are stated from the perspective of a physicist (apparently).  Since physics is by and large a matter of fact not opinion, I wondered if the statements above are really fact or fiction.

Comment: (1) we're not a forum. Beware, you may be banned for saying that ;-) (2) Yep, but climate change can get controversial, and IIRC opinion is divided on it, even within the physics community. And the opinion guides the fact that'sused :/ .Skeptics.SE would have given you a referenced answer--then again, it wouldn't be hard to find comtradictory scientific publications--and might look at it neutrally.

Comment: That being said, I think `@Terry's answer below is great, so no need to migrate.. Unless you really want to be sure :)

Comment: Oh come on, nobody gets banned for calling this site a forum ;-) (although of course we'd prefer you didn't). And welcome to Physics Stack Exchange, William! Like Terry said in his answer, kudos to you for asking for a review of the claim.

Comment: @manishearth: there really isn't any division or controversy over the basic facts of climate change. The idea that any controversy exists is purely a political fabrication. The details are certainly complex, but the fundamental rules of thermodynamics and absorption spectra have been settled science for over a century.

Comment: @ColinK Hmm.. Didn't know that, thanks for the info! When you say 'basic facts', I assume there's a controversy elsewhere.. Could you explain? (Preferably on chat, though I may have to leave soon)

Comment: What you guys think about what Ivar Giaever did? Why is he, as nobel prize winner, doing this? I see some of our physicists here in Croatia doing the same thing and misleading the public.  What is their agenda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article you quoted frankly reads very poorly. It quotes a lot of stuff without once noting that greenhouse effects absolutely are real and critical to the earth being habitable. I don't know who this fellow is, but if he posted here directly I'd give it an instant negative vote.

You, sir, I'm giving a thumbs up for taking the trouble to ask in a forum where you are likely to get some answers. More people should do that when they hear odd science claims!

Now, with that said, it's absolutely true that both carbon dioxide and methane are bit players in the overall greenhouse effect.

The main greenhouse is water vapor, by about two orders of magnitude. My recollection without looking it up is that 97 to 98 percent of the greenhouse effect is caused by water vapor. This is why it gets so cold in the desert at night, for example.

The Nobel-prize winning models for global warming do *not* invoke direct warming from carbon dioxide. Instead, they postulate and model using computer programs the idea that the very small additive impacts of carbon dioxide, methane, and other minor greenhouse gases throw off the balance of the major player, water vapor. I do not know how they do that part of the model. It has to be complicated, since water vapor levels vary with near-fractal complexity from day to day and from region to region.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added some references I found to other work by the blog post author.

Comment: But certain geologists disagree on the fact that the present increase in global temerature is because of increase in greenhouse gases. They say that earth actually have a cycle of heat and ice ages. So, what we are seeing is actually those rather than an effect of greenhouse emission.

Comment: I have doubts about your numbers and corresponding picture you paint here.  If we go by the most widely accepted IPCC scenarios and models, then the radiative forcing from CO2 alone contributes about 1 degree C.  Although there are contributions from other gases, this is over half of the total anthropogenic forcing value.  Then water vapor has the effect of increasing this to 5-7 degrees C.  This corresponds to 700-800 ppm CO2 and can be verified with Wikipedia and 10 cells of calcs in Excel.  Now, this is my conceptual picture and I think it conflicts with what you wrote.

Comment: Hey, Terry--- you're answer is good, +1, but the CO2 is not negligible, as AlanSE says. Could you modify it a bit? You can get rough estimates for CO2 impact from ice-core data, and they match observations from human-generated CO2, so the complicated models are not necessary. But they do give confidence in the projections of warming, and the location of the warming.

Comment: Ron, will do, I'm not happy with my lack of specs either. I've read papers that had specifics on relative roles and recall what they looked like, but I need to dig them up and find out the details. The ones I saw were not from the ice core data - those are absolutely fascinating for multiple reasons - but from a physical properties analysis. Sometime this week; I won't be happy myself until I can recover the specifics of what I was paraphrasing from memory.

Comment: @Adrian Please don't make large changes to the physics content of another user's answer without their approval. The change you made left this answer inconsistent with itself. Feel free to provide the correction in an answer of your own devising, or to bring that reference to Terry's attention and ask him to change the answer (or to accept that edit; or allow you to have another go; or whatever).

Comment: dmckee, wow, thanks for the heads up. I've never had anyone do this before. I approved nothing and had no idea it had been changed. Phone access only right now; I'll look as best I can.

Comment: I'm the guilty party for flagging Adrian's edit. Adrian's edit was correct in the sense of correcting misinformation. This answer is so bogus! However, Adrian's edit was very incorrect in the sense that a radical change to an answer without the permission of the author is WRONG. It doesn't matter if the answer is incorrect. Rewording an answer to make it differ from the original intent of the original author of an answer is very, very wrong.

Comment: The link Adrian gave gave is invalid and so impossible to access. The one paper I could find at that site indicated that 95% of heat retention is due to water and carbon dioxide — which remains nicely ambiguous, but hardly and endorsement of this curious 60% claim. A good link to a peer-reviewed paper might be a nice — you surely must know of several, given your confidence?

Comment: @TerryBollinger - See table 3 in [Kiehl & Trenberth, (1997). Earth's annual global mean energy budget. *Bulletin of the American Meteorological Society*, 78(2), 197-208](http://www.geo.utexas.edu/courses/387H/PAPERS/kiehl.pdf).

Comment: @DavidHammen, thanks! My original "best recollection" figure was, incidentally, based on going over some of the more arcane technical innards of the model that won the Nobel Prize, so please don't think it was something I scarfed off of some sketchy web site. I am myself puzzled at the disparity, given where I (think?) I first got that number. The Nobel-winning model is profoundly non-linear due to its deep dependence on multi-modal amplification cycles, so my suspicion is that the different figures reflect different choices in the selection of cutoff points within these rather complex cycles.

Comment: @DavidHammen, this is a nice paper, but it is _way_ too old (17 years) for this topic, especially given that far more recent Nobel Prize for the same topic area. Suggestion: See if you can find some way to access the details of the latter model, and I'll try to do the same. For multiple reasons my search may be a bit slow, though.

Comment: @TerryBollinger -- Do you realize that (1) that Nobel prize was a Nobel Peace Prize rather than a science prize, (2) the reports issued by the cited organization, the IPCC, go strongly against what you are saying, and (3) the IPCC reports in fact rely heavily on the Earth radiation budget analyses by Trenberth and others? Here's the most recent IPCC report: http://www.ipcc.ch/report/ar5/wg1/ .

Comment: @DavidHammen, thanks for getting that excellent info together! I wish I had time to explore it right now, and perhaps I can later, but since my last note I seem to have ended up in a hospital again. I hope I can re-engage on this at some point soon. Others: Read David's references! Look, analyze, and decide on your own!

Comment: The attributions stated are a bit overrated. I remember (without having sources at hand anymore, though) water vapor to account for up to 70 % of the green house effect, and CO2 for up to 10 %. And then methane a bit less and ozone on the fourth place.

Comment: Hmm... do you have a ref?

Answer (score 6):

Let's look a bit closer at the claims of Doug Cotton, and of  Claes Johnson, whose work Doug relies upon. It's important because this is one of the strongest claims made by those who choose to reject the notion of anthropogenic climate change.

Here's the core claim, from Doug Coton:

> The assumption is made that so-called "backradiation" from a cold atmosphere is able to transfer thermal energy to a surface which is warmer than the source of the radiation. This is a physical impossibility as is proven theoretically by Prof Claes Johnson and empirically by Prof. Nasif Nahle

The claim, contradictory to over a century of thermodynamics, is that a body will only radiate heat towards bodies colder than it, and never towards bodies hotter than it. Note that this is **not** a claim about **net** heat transfer, but about any radiated heat.

Apparently, this happens through [the following mechanism](http://claesjohnson.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/wise-and-fools-of-backradiation.html) according to Professor Claes Johnson:

> [a body] reads the temperature of the surrounding from its spectrum, and then decides to cool or warm depending on its own temperature

The Johnson/Cotton theory is that almost everyone other than them [misinterprets](http://claesjohnson.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/what-is-2nd-law-of-radiation-2.html) the Stefan-Boltzmann Law, and that there is [no such thing](http://claesjohnson.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/light-waves-or-particles.html) as photons of infra-red radiation.

And the problem with all of this is that this is an extraordinary claim that lacks any evidence at all. Thermodynamics, the theory of photons, and of black-body radiation, have all made astonishingly successful predictions, and are supported by many decades of empirical evidence.

Comment: Thanks. I'd also got the feeling from reading Cotton's paper that he is not to be taken seriously, but I don't have the theoretical background to contradict his claims. However, common sense leads me to think that the atmosphere will radiate in all directions, including towards the earth, whatever their relative temperatures, so his claim that the earth cannot be affected by the CO2 in the atmosphere is clearly nonsense. I've seen various discussions indicating that the anti-warming community rejects his thesis too.

Comment: ``[a body] reads the temperature of the surrounding from its spectrum, and then decides to cool or warm depending on its own temperature'' Are we sure Professor Johnson isn't a comedian?

Answer (score -1):

I believe the professor Johnson, for one simple reason, If you heat a piece of metal and subject it to air temperature of the room it will cool off fast at first, then as the air and metal temperatures come close to the same, before slowly coming the the normal ambient of the room, this is all basic thermodynamics, 
  And in my limited knowledge, there are a lot of things that I still am learning about, however there is on thing that is conveniently omitted in the GH Gas circles, is water vapor, and the variable amount of sunlight we receive each day. 
  we on earth see the same sun each day, but have no idea of how much radiation it sends our way, and that the sun spots actually increase the amount of radiated heat we get, these gusts of solar radiation (winds)have been correlated with ice core samples that show that during the little ice age a few hundred yrs back, correspond to a period of little or no sunspots during that period, and we have just recently come through a period high spot activity,  but when all appeared calm seem's that 2 spots have reappeared, Personally I think it's absurd that whatever amount of CO 2 we add to the atmosphere, there is no way that we can overpower the sun and water vapor.